# Linux SSH client for iPhone

Tags: linux, iphone, ssh

Is there any good SSH client for iphone on Linux OS?

I really need one; `ssh` on Terminal does not really help me that much.

Comment: I don't get the question. Do you need a ssh client to run on Linux so you can ssh into your iphone? And what more can you possibly ask for than ssh "on terminal"?

Comment: What do you want to do? what's wrong with "ssh" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing better than the original `ssh` running in some Terminal application :)

Comment: I agree, ssh is sufficient.

Comment: ive read trough a couple of stuff, and i found an auto-script that can handle everything for me (so i dont have to type in commands, which i really hate with a lot of files), so i accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

I use TouchTerm on my iPhone.  It works well enough for simple operations.

Comment: is this 'from' or 'to' linux?